# Skewness per row

Tags: r, loops, missing-data

I have following data:

```
d1    <- c(-10,2,3,4,5,6, NA, NA, NA);
d2    <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7, NA, NA); 
d3    <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,700, 800, 900);
d     <- rbind(d1, d2, d3); d <- data.matrix(d)
```

I would now like to measure the skewness of each row of d (or each participant). I know about the function skewness(x) of the moments package, however, there seems to be a problem. I tried following code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(d)){
skew[i] <- as.numeric(skewness(d[i]))
}
```

Do you have any idea what can be wrong? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply`:

```
apply(d, 1, skewness, na.rm =TRUE)
```

A fixed version of your `for` loop:

```
skew <- vector("numeric", nrow(d))  # first pre allocate to hold the result
for (i in 1:nrow(d)){
  skew[i] <- skewness(d[i, ], na.rm=TRUE) # your matrix indexing was wrong
}
setNames(skew, rownames(d))  # just for names
```

Note that your matrix indexing was completely wrong, and as `NA`s are present in your matrix, you need to set `na.rm=TRUE` to skip them, read `?skewness`. I prefer using `apply` instead of a `for` loop, read about `?apply`.

Answer (score 1):

From the `Rfast` package, you can use:

`colskewness(d)`